# Angular 6 Simple way to bind multiple texbox values to dropdown options

Tags: angular

I have a simple data entry form like where you enter the name of upto 5 siblings

[image]

html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="ChildInfo" [(ngModel)]="ChildInfo.sibling1UnderFiveName" >
    <input type="text" *ngIf="ChildInfo" [(ngModel)]="ChildInfo.sibling2UnderFiveName" >
```

In a different tab, I have a dropdown where a user can select if any of the siblings entered in the above textboxes are also receiving special care or have allergies.
[image]

Code for dropdowns is like this

How can I get the options of the dropdowns to be dynamically populated with the values entered in the 5 text boxes ?

```
   <select   *ngIf="ChildInfo" [(ngModel)]="ChildInfo.child1PhysicalMedicalCondition"  id="child1PhMedCon" >
                                <option></option>               
                            </select>
```

My component.ts file is like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (childId > 0){
                 this.data.getChildInfo(childId).subscribe(
                  (data: ChildInfo) => {
                    this.ChildInfo = data;
                    this.isLoadingResults = false; },
                  (error) => {
                    return this.loadingMessage = 'There has been an error -' + error.message;
                   }
                );
                 } else {
                      this.isLoadingResults = false;
                       this.ChildInfo =  new ChildInfo;
                }
      },
     (error) => {
      return this.loadingMessage = 'There has been an error  -' + error.message;
     });
}
```

What I am asking is, if someone enters Names in the first 5 text boxes, I would like them to be immediately added to the dropdown options in second tab.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not just set the `ngModel` on them, as you have done on the original 5 textboxes?

Comment: @user184994 they bind to different ngModel.

Comment: Okay, then set the `ngModel` of the 5 textboxes to the value you want them to display

Comment: Share more code how you are storing the ChildInfo information in the first screen.